# What does this error mean: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

When I try to test run this I keep getting a null exception for line 51:
                    songs[i].title=Recording.setTitle();
The method seems to be called fine, so why isn't songs[i].title being set?
I'm pretty new to navigating classes so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Recording {
    String title;
    String artist;
    String time;

     String getTitle(){
        return title;
     }


    String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    String getTime(){
        return time;
    }

     static String setTitle(){
        Scanner title_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the title of your recording?");
        String title_received = title_input.nextLine();
        return title_received;
    }

     String setArtist(){
        Scanner artist_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Who is the artist of your recording?");
        String artist_received = artist_input.nextLine();
        return artist_received;
    }

     String setTime(){
        Scanner time_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How long is your recording of your recording?");
        String time_received = time_input.nextLine();
        return time_received;
    }
}
public class RecordingSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Recording[] songs = new Recording[5];

            for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i){
                songs[i].title=Recording.setTitle();
                System.out.println(songs[i].title);
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: The key is that a *reference* array is initially filled with null values. Think of it as being similar to creating an egg carton. You can't use any eggs until you first fill the carton with eggs. So for instance with your songs array, you first need to assign Recording objects to each item in the array before you can call methods on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving this error because although you declared and allocated an array of 5 `Recording` objects, you never actually instantiated any objects in that array.

Try adding a line here:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i){
                songs[i] = new Recording(); //invoke a valid object constructor here                                  
                songs[i].title=Recording.setTitle();
```